# Как вставить уменьшенную версию изображений {$xf['poster'namefield]} в этом хаке DLE?

Tags: поиск, dle

Постер в быстром поиске через доп. поле и короткую новость

Вот хак
https://devcraft.club/threads/poster-v-bystrom-poiske-cherez-dop-pole-i-korotkuju-novost.12/

А как вставить уменьшенную версию изображений для поле {$xf['poster']} а то он даёт вот такой результат /2017-11/88_nekojiru-so.jpg а для уменьшенной копии (thumb) нужно добавить в ссылку директорию /2019-10/thumb/58488_nekojiru-so.jpg

вот разница
/2017-11/88_nekojiru-so.jpg
/2017-11/thumb/88_nekojiru-so.jpg

как реализовать ?